# Redux only works after forced refresh (with context/provider)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

So I have a problem with react-redux. I have a SignIn screen where people can enter their username and password. These credentials are send to the server, and if the are correct, an auth token is send to the client. I store this auth token in redux. To "visualize" my problem, I've added the (simplified) code below. Below the code is some more explanation.

```
// folder structure
// ----------------
// - App.js
// - screens/
//     - SignIn.js
//     - Main.js
// - navigators/
//     - Stack.js (stack navigator for SignIn.js and Main.js)
// - store/
//     - actions/
//         - Auth.js
// - providers/
//     - Auth.js


// App.js (simplified)
// -------------------
...
import { AuthProvider } from './providers/Auth'
import StackNavigator from './navigators/Stack'
...
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <AuthProvider>
                <StackNavigator />
            </AuthProvider>
        </Provider>
}


// screens/SignIn.js (simplified)
// ------------------------------

...
import { saveAuthToken } from '../store/actions/Auth'
...
let req = await fetch('URL_TO_SERVER', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        username,
        password
    }
let status = req.status
let res = await req.json()
if (status === 200) {
    // everything is ok
    dispatch(saveAuthToken(res.authToken))
    props.navigation.navigate('Main')
}

// screens/Main.js (simplified)
// ----------------------------

...
import { AuthContext } from '../providers/Auth'
import { deleteAuthToken } from '../store/actions/Auth'
...
const { token, state } = useContext(AuthContext)
...
useEffect(() => {
    if (state === 'unauthenticated') {
        dispatch(deleteAuthToken())
        props.navigation.navigate('SignIn')
    }
}, [state])

// providers/Auth.js (simplified)
// ------------------------------

...
import React, { createContext } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
...
export const AuthContext = createContext()
export const AuthProvider = props => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const [token, setToken] = useState(useSelector(state => state.token.auth))
    const [state, setState] = useState('pending')
    const authenticateHandler = async () => {
        // do stuff with a fetch to the server
        // to validate the auth token
        // let's say the state of the auth token is
        // reflected in the status code of the response
        let req = await fetch(...)
        let status = req.status
        let res = await req.json()
        if (status === 400) {
            setState('expired')
        }
        if (status === 200) {
            setState('authenticated')
        }
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (token !== null) {
            authenticateHandler()
        } else {
            setState('unauthenticated')
        }
    }, [state])
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ token, state }}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

When a user successfully signs in on (screen) **SignIn**, the auth token is saved in the redux through `dispatch(saveAuthToken())`. After this, the user is redirected to (screen) **Main**. Here, the problem occurs! When the user is send to (screen) **Main**, his state is still 'unauthenticated' because the `useSelector(state => state.token.auth)`returns `null` the first time. **Only when I manually refresh the code, the token in successfully fetched from redux and the state changes to 'authenticated'.** So the problem is that I cannot check te "real" state of the user (authenticated or unauthenticated) before I do a hard refresh. Because I delete the token on (screen) **Main** when the user is unauthenticated, I get stuck in an infinite loop between SignIn and Main.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With redux, you can use `mapStateToProps` to bring the value of a redux reducer into your component. I presume you are already doing this, but if not [read up on it](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate).

With that, you have access to the value and as soon as it changes your component will update. You watch this update, and if it has a new token value in it, you save it to your state.

With hooks, that would be done with `useEffect`. The second argument is watched and the function runs when it changes, so you'd put the mapped props value there.

Without hooks, you'd watch for it in `componentDidUpdate` which receives the old props as the first argument, allowing you to check `oldProps.myMappedReduxValue !== this.props.myMappedReduxValue`.

Comment: I use ``useSelector()`` the get the value, so I have access to the value in the AuthProvider-component. I'll try with the useEffect()-function.